# Using WebView in PhoneGap Open Home Page by Putting Login ID and Password using Code

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap, I need to load load a website Home Page(say www.facebook.com) in my app and login Internally (putting User ID and Password using coding, I have use id and password in storage)

How to do?